# How do I restore npm root folder to the default one?

Tags: node.js, npm

I just installed ionic with npm and when I run -v to check the version it gives me an error and that says "ionic is not recognized as an internal or external command". Basically it's like I never installed the package in the first place. After a while I figured that my default folder for npm has changed.

I'm using Windows 10 so I think it should be something like 
`User\MyUser\AppData\npm\node_modules" or maybe "User\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules" but for whatever reason npm installs stuff inside "AppData\Local`

I asked around a bit (even here on stackoverflow) and found out that if I edit the environmental variable "PATH" things should work, so I did it and ionic now works fine

However today I tried to install express and the same error popped up. I checked my PATH again just to be sure and it's pointing to the "Local" folder where my node_modules are. Ionic still works right now and it's in the same folder, so I have no idea why express doesn't work.

I want to fix things once and for all, how do I change the place where the node_modules are? How do I go back to `AppData` or `Roaming` or whatever folder Windows 10 uses by default?

Comment: I think `$NPM_PACKAGES` is what sets where global packages are installed, not `$PATH`.  Are you installing locally or globally with `npm -g install`?

Comment: I always use npm -g

Comment: When you say you "always" do `npm -g install`, are you doing that for express too?  There's generally few things you need to install globally.  Libraries like express and like 95% of everything else out there, you ought to just install locally.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. I'm pretty new to this stuff as you might have guessed, thanks for the advice. I tried both ways with express by the way. I did it locally, saw it wasn't working so I removed it and tried again with -g to see if anything changed. Then I figured out the problem was something else.